# Is it considered as bad practice to redirect in header with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-head

Let's assume that I load a filtering page, and based of an earlier set cookie, I want to reload the page by adding a few query parameters to my url.
Something like this:

```
<head>
    <script>
        if (need_to_load_with_different_params) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href + params_from_cookie;
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

I don't remember seeing web applications using this kind of pattern. Is there a good reason for that?
Should I move such logic to server-side by all means?

(using `jquery.cookie` to simplify cookie reading if that makes any difference)

Comment: You may see a FOUC, but there's no issues with that code. It would be better to do this server side though, if possible.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossanm, you are right, I am doing it on server side.

Comment: In order to be able for anyone to answer your question you will first have to explain what "dangerous" means in this context.

Comment: I updated my question, is it still considered as unclear?

Comment: Not so much unclear as it is broad. I could write a book about "security problems, maintenance problems, user acceptance issues".

Answer (score 3):

As commented by @Rory McCrossan, it would be better to do this server side.

Several reasons for that:

- The user could have JavaScript disabled
- The navigation will feel much cluttered (client request -> server response -> JavaScript parsing -> client request -> server reponse -> HTML parsing before actually having the whole page)

---

**Original Answer**: It shouldn't be considered secure: in any case the rest of the content of the page will be downloaded by the user (if JavaScript is disabled, the redirect won't happen)

Comment: What makes it not secure in specific? Sure the user could see content before  the redirect fires, but how is that not secure?

Comment: If the content in the body should not be accessible by unauthorized users (and if that verification is made in JS). *Considering the changes in the question, my answer is now quite irrelevant*